# C/C++ program calling .NET - Garbage collection

Tags: .net, c, garbage-collection, managed

If a C/C++ program (running as a windows service) calls a function in .Net, how is garbage collection handled? I don't have control over the C/C++ program as it is a third party program. It can however be "hooked" to a C/C++ function, which in turn can call something in .Net.

Here is an example of a C++ program calling a function in a .Net class, and I plan to use a similar approach:

http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/695387/Calling-Csharp-NET-methods-from-unmanaged-C-Cplusp

On the .Net side, if I do something like creating generic lists or create an XmlDocument, will the .Net runtime magically kick in and do its job (with regards to garbage collection) (even though the calling program is not running CLR to start with)?